# Mysterious error that only appears when declaring the last array

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse

When declaring an array, the IDE (Eclipse) gives me an error. However, if I declare another array immediately after, the error shifts to the next array as if by magic. I can try to add more and more arrays, but I'll only be delaying the inevitable. This leaves me with 2 questions: why does error happen and how do I fix it?

```
import java.util.Arrays; 
public class BattleshipGrid {
    private char[][] arr1 = new char[10][10];
    private char[][] arr2 = new char[10][10];
    private char[][] arr3 = new char[10][10]; 
    private char[][] arr4 = new char[10][10];//"Syntax error on token ";", { expected
    for (char[] i: arr2) {
        for(char j: i) {
            i[j]='X';
        }
    }
    public static void main (String[] args) {
    }
}
```

Comment: `for` can't be inside the class directly, it must be in a method. So, you can try putting it inside the main method (while using `static` on the other variables, or don't use main method, use a non static method)

Comment: @user9335240 You can post your comment as an answer in order to get the credit you deserve for it

Comment: Actually I find the description of the question very funny :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For loop itself can't be in a class. The class is just place for declarations, not for code. Code in Java is in methods only.

So you have 2 solutions. Either put your code inside the `main` method:

```
import java.util.Arrays; 
public class BattleshipGrid {
    private static char[][] arr1 = new char[10][10]; // Made it static so that
         // it would be bound to the class object itself, so that you can see
         // it from the main method which is also static and bound to the class
         // object
    private static char[][] arr2 = new char[10][10];
    private static char[][] arr3 = new char[10][10]; 
    private static char[][] arr4 = new char[10][10];

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        for (char[] i: arr2) {
            for(char j: i) {
                i[j]='X';
            }
        }

    }
}
```

The other (which is the better) solution is to create an instance of the class inside the main method.

```
import java.util.Arrays; 
public class BattleshipGrid {
    private char[][] arr1 = new char[10][10];
    private char[][] arr2 = new char[10][10];
    private char[][] arr3 = new char[10][10]; 
    private char[][] arr4 = new char[10][10];

    public void initializeTheGrid() {
        for (char[] i: arr2) {
            for(char j: i) {
                i[j]='X';
            }
        }
    }


    public static void main (String[] args) {
        BattleshipGrid grid = new BattleshipGrid();
        grid.initializeTheGrid();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for following up. I figured it out after your initial comment by just placing it in its own method, but I also like the other approach.

Answer (score 2):

Your for loop must reside in a method of some kind.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
public class BattleshipGrid
{
    private char[][] arr1 = new char[10][10];
    private char[][] arr2 = new char[10][10];
    private char[][] arr3 = new char[10][10]; 
    private char[][] arr4 = new char[10][10];

    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        for ( char[] i: arr2)
        {
            for ( char j: i)
            {
                j = 'X';
            }
        }
    }
}
```